# Using pointers instead of an array

Tags: c, pointers

I wrote this program a few weeks ago using arrays and now I need to use pointers instead of using arrays.  I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing that so any tips would be appreciated!  Thanks!  :D

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int showArray(int row);
int exchangeRow(int row1, int row2);

int x, y;
int array[10][10];
int j;
int k;
int inputrow;
int inputcolumn;
int scanrow;
int temp;
int row1;
int row2;

int main() {

    // Initialize array
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
          printf("\n");
          for(k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
                array[j][k] = j * 10 + k;
                printf("%d ", array[j][k]);
          }
    }
    printf("\n \n");

    // Print out selected row
    printf("Type in a number for the corresponding row to be printed \n");
    scanf("%d", &inputrow);
    if(inputrow >= 0 && inputrow < 10) {
             for(j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                   printf("%d ", array[inputrow][j]);
             }
    }
    printf("\n \n");

    //Print out selected column
    printf("Type in a number for the corresponding column to be printed \n");
    scanf("%d", &inputcolumn);
    if(inputcolumn >= 0 && inputcolumn < 10) {
             for(j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                   printf("%d ", array[j][inputcolumn]);
             }
    }
    printf("\n \n");

    printf("Type in a number for the row that method showArray will print \n");
    scanf("%d", &scanrow);
    showArray(scanrow);
    printf("\n \n");

    printf("Type in two numbers for the rows that method exchangeRow will switch \n");
    scanf("%d %d", &row1, &row2);
    exchangeRow(row1, row2);
    printf("\n \n");

    system("PAUSE");
}

int showArray(int row) {
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
           printf("%d ", array[row][j]);
     }
}

int exchangeRow(int row1, int row2) {
    if(row1 >= 0 && row1 < 10 && row2 >= 0 && row2 < 10) {
           temp = row1;
           row1 = row2;
           row2 = temp;
           printf("The first row now holds the values: ");
           showArray(row1);
           printf("\n");
           printf("The second row now holds the values: ");
           showArray(row2);
    }
}
```

Comment: What needs to be pointers? Arrays and pointers are very tightly coupled ideas in C, with an array boiling down to a pointer to the first element.

Comment: @Ben: An expression of array type is *converted* to a pointer to the first element in most contexts (this is commonly referred to as "decaying"). One might infer from your "boiling down to" comment that arrays are really pointers, a common misconception.

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/). It explains the (often confusing) relationship between C arrays and pointers better than most of the answers here are doing.

Comment: And please tell us *exactly* what your requirement is. Saying you "need to use pointers instead of using arrays" could mean any of several things.

Answer (score 6):

I take it you mean "using dynamic memory allocation"...

The way a lot of people do 2D arrays dynamically is like this:

```
const size_t nrows = 10, ncols = 10;

int **array = malloc( nrows * sizeof(int*) );
for( i = 0; i < nrows; i++ ) {
    array[i] = malloc( ncols * sizeof(int) );
}
```

But I hate this.  If you are doing production code, this can be very slow.  It's also harder to handle the case where you run out of memory, and there's no guaranteed locality of your array.  Plus, it's ugly to free:

```
for( i = 0; i < nrows; i++ ) free(array[i]);
free(array);
```

In memory, your static `array[10][10]` is one contiguous block.  So you should do the same:

```
int **array = malloc( nrows * sizeof(int*) );
array[0] = malloc( nrows * ncols * sizeof(int) );
for( i = 1; i < nrows; i++ ) {
    array[i] = array[i-1] + ncols;
}
```

To free that:

```
free(array[0]);
free(array);
```

I often take this a step further, and do a single memory allocation instead of two.  That way I have just one pointer.  But I won't do that here.  You have to be a little conscious of alignment, and the code is a little messier.  It's an optimization that usually you don't need.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

To be more specific, what is required of you is to use *pointer notation* instead of *array notaiton*

This would probably mean that your 2 dimensional array should be allocated as an array of pointers. Also it's individual elements should be accessed using pointers rather than the usual array indexing.

For e.g.

```
int * a = malloc(10 * sizeof(int)); // allocate memory for 10 integers
*a = 1;        // assign first element of array
*(a+1) = 2;    // assign second
```

The above was for 1D array. Extend it to multiple dimensions as in your original program.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily mean that the way the array is allocated needs to be changed. You can use a pointer variable to traverse an array. The OP hasn't really told us enough to guess what the specific requirement is.

Comment: Yeah but it's better that you change the entire notation. At any rate it is more material to learn nonetheless

Comment: Better in what way? The question smells like homework (though we no longer use that tag); if it is, then whether the allocation should be changed depends on how the assignment is phrased.

Comment: Better in the way that "using arrays and now I need to use pointers" does not clarify whether it includes allocation too. As a teacher, I would take that implicit if my intention is for the student to grasp pointer notation completely. Even if that is not the case, this would only improve credibility of his solution to homework while removing the risk of teaching expecting allocation included but not specified clearly in the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare an array, such as `int arr[4];`, `arr` actually "points" to a location in memory with 4 "spaces" that holds an integer each.

`&arr` means "address of" `arr`.

So, a pointer to arr could be defined as:

```
int *ptr = &arr[0];
```

But how would you get the *data* that `ptr` points to? The answer is:

```
*ptr;
```

But, this will only show you the first value of the data stored in the first "space" that `arr` occupies. To get the others in the array, all you need to do is increment your pointer along the space in memory, like so:

```
ptr++;
```

Further information can be found here: http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~pdiloren/C++_Pointers/neighbor.htm

Comment: I've been downvoted and scolded in the past for saying "arrays are actually pointers".  You mean to say that when you pass an array as a pointer it is interpreted as a pointer.

Comment: Or the name of an array returns the address of first element which can be treated as a pointer in most cases.

Comment: `int *ptr = &arr;` is invalid. `ptr` is of type `int*`; `&arr` is of type `int (*p)[4]`. The expression `arr`, which names an array object, is implicitly *converted* to a pointer to the array's first element. Either `int *ptr = arr;` or `int *ptr = &arr[0];` would be valid.