# Is my implementation of pointers and dynamic allocation correct?

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

I am studying pointers in C/C++ and as my little project to learn this problematic I am trying to develop a simple application doing operations with matrixies. I want to ask if this way I am using pointers and dynamic allocation in is correct or I am making it wrong. Thanks :)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int numberRows;
int numberCollumns;
void getSize()
{
   printf("Write down size of matrix in format Rows Collumns: ");
   scanf("%i %i", &numberRows, &numberCollumns);
}

void getMatrix(int *m[])
{
   int x = 0;
   int y = 0;
   while(x<numberRows)
   {
      while(y<numberCollumns)
      {
      scanf("%i", &m[x][y]);
      y++;        
      }
   x++;
   y = 0;
   }
}

void writeMatrix(int *m[])
{
   int x = 0;
   int y = 0;
   while(x<numberRows)
   {
      while(y<numberCollumns)
      {
      printf("%i ", m[x][y]);
      y++;        
      }
   printf("\n");
   x++;
   y = 0;
   }
}

int main()
{
   getSize();
   int **matrix;
   matrix = (int**)malloc(numberRows*sizeof(int*));
   int x = 0;
   while(x < numberCollumns)
   {
      matrix[x] = (int*)malloc(numberCollumns*sizeof(int));
      x++;
   }
   getMatrix(matrix);
   printf("\n\nMatrix: \n");
   writeMatrix(matrix);


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is C style code, not C++. C/C++ is not a language, pick one or the other.

Comment: Have you tested this code? Does it behave as you expected?

Comment: Probably better for the codereview site.

Comment: Well I am using C functions instead of C++ objects, but I believe that  the core of language is same in both C and Cpp. And yes, its working well, but I am not sure if I am using pointers and dynamic allocation in correct way :)

Comment: It's not the same.  You're using malloc , the C standard library, and C IO routines. This is C, not C++, they are two different languages.  Also, don't cast the return value of malloc in C.  It is unnecessary (and pointer type can be implicitly converted from a `void*`) and it can hide an error in older compilers (i.e., you forgot to include <stdlib.h>.  You're also leaking memory.  Every call to `malloc` needs a corresponding call to `free` somewhere.  Sure, the OS will probably clean up after you in this case, but it's a bad habit to get into.

Comment: Meant to say "*any* pointer type", not "*and* pointer type"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem:

```
while(x < numberCollumns)
{
   matrix[x] = (int*)malloc(numberCollumns*sizeof(int));
   x++;
}
```

Your loop condition is wrong. What if the number of rows and columns do not match up?
Also, I do not seeing any corresponding calls to `free`.

As for code style, your while loops would look better as for loops:

```
for(int x = 0; x < numberRows; ++x)
{
    matrix[x] = (int*)malloc(numberCollumns*sizeof(int));
}
```

**Side Note**

The code is pure C (well except for the casting of the return from `malloc`). C++ code would look a lot different.

Answer (score 0):

It looks okay, except as Jesse Good pointed out your construction should loop over `numberRows`, not `numberCollumns` (*PS* only one L in 'column').

I think you have a misleading choice of variable names.  Your matrix is laid out as `matrix[rows][columns]`, but you index it using `[x][y]`.  Traditionally, `x` is a horizontal index and `y` is vertical.  Using `x` to select the row (which is a vertical dimension) is going to confuse you one day.  Either reverse the use of these, or do what mathematicians do (use `i` and `j`).

Regarding the 2D matrix itself, I would avoid individual allocations for every row for reasons of cache locality and efficiency.  I answered a question the other day and provided some thoughts on this:  [Using pointers instead of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888845/using-pointers-instead-of-an-array/12888976#12888976)

Finally, and this is just a general style thing...  Why don't you use `for` loops when you are just iterating over your rows/columns.  It's much easier to read, and less accident-prone ("whoops I forgot to reset and/or increment my counter").

Oh yes, and if this is pure C, do not cast the result of your `malloc` calls.